# Why do people say C is more efficient?

Tags: c, programming-languages, performance

People always say that C is more efficient than any other high level language.I don't understand why. I  know assembly is efficient because it has a close relation to machine language .

But C and C++ or ruby,lets say,they are all going to be 'translated' into machine language,right? By more efficient,does it mean the machine  code is better,or it takes less time to be 'translated'  into machine code? What if there is some compiler or interpreter that can produce faster,also result in better machine code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I know assembly is efficient because it has a close relation to machine language.

No, it does not. it has a 1.1 relation - it is a written representation of exact machine code commands. It is a mnemonic language - basically replacing byte codes with another representation. All higher langauges miss that.

> But c and c++ or ruby,let say,they are all gonna be 'translated' into machine 
>   language,right?

Yes, but the question is when and how efficient. low level languages - and C is one - allow less advanced constructs and are thus closer to assembler and easier for the compiler to optimize.

> By more efficient,does it mean the machine code is better,or it takes less time to be 
>   'translated' into machine code?

Outside of just in time compiled languages or interpreters NOONE cares about how much time it takes to translate. C is statically translated, once, then executed.

> What if there is some compiler or interpreter that can produce faster,with better machine 
>   code?

Then the statement is not true. Funny enough, that is not really the case - it is not that easy to make a super efficient compiler for higher languages. Basically you keep asking why a super sports car is so fast & state it would not be considered to so fast anymore when every Fiat Panda would have more horsepower - but sadly they don't have and never will have.

Comment: Your answer is concise yet clear.Thanks a lot!

Comment: Minor point re. translation time: Compiler performance *does* matter - nobody wants to wait an hour for a debug build. For instance, almost no compiler tries to find an optimal solution when allocating registers (by graph coloring), they all use heuristics and faster algorithms which sometimes result in worse code but is expotentially more efficent (graph coloring is NP-complete). And aside from optimization, half of all parsing algorithms are motivated by performance.

Comment: Seriously? I would not care. You could always turn that off for an overnight build for release. Some systems are large, with unit tests etc.

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of different issues at play here, so a full answer would be very long.

Some high-level languages are higher-level than others. C is not very high-level.

Different languages make different trade-offs. Some languages focus on ease of development, programmer productivity, preventing common errors, automation etc.

Others focus on speed/efficiency. C is one of the latter, partly due to its age and history.

*Given the same level of effort*, a C program is not necessarily faster than the equivalent in another languages, especially on modern multi-core systems. However, C exposes more possibilities for low-level optimisations, if you have the time to write them. The downside is that these optimisations are error-prone, and getting them wrong normally crashes your program completely.

Comment: Thanks,really made it more clear to me!

Comment: "Some high-level languages are higher-level than others. C is not very high-level" -- agreed, it's just high-level enough ;)